# By what algorithmic process do systemic functional linguistics think surface language is generated?

Tags: systemic-functional, production

I am very interested in the idea of systemic functional linguistics as an alternative to the simplistic production grammars advanced by the minimalist program.  What I don't understand is how SFL proposes we produce language instead.  It makes great sense to me as a computer scientist without a background in linguistics that it might require some complicated constraint solving, but I haven't seen anyone describe a detailed account of such a constraint solving process.  When it comes down to it, how do we turn the network of associations we have with different words into a string of words, according to SFL?